# How to determine whether hang up triggered by timeout or by user request when "Gather" command is used?

Tags: twilio

We are using `Gather` command (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to ask user a question. We do not use automatic voicemail detection because 2-seconds delay makes our product much worse.

Accidentally some users hang up instead of choosing 1 or 2, and some users have a voicemail. We need to detect - whether it was a hangup by timeout option (so it's most likely a voicemail) of `Gather` or it was a user-triggered hangup.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Whilst the hangup wouldn't look different in the status of the call, you could use a property of `<Gather>` to fix this for you though.

When you go through a `<Gather>` and the timeout fires, the TwiML will continue. You could then `<Redirect>` to another endpoint that records that the `<Gather>` times out and then hangs up. Something like:

```
<Response>
  <Gather timeout="10" numDigits="1">
    <Say>Enter 1 for this or 2 for that</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>http://example.com/gather_timeout</Redirect>
</Response>
```

Then the redirect might run some code and then hangup.

```
<?php
  // Record the CallSid and that it was a Gather timeout
?>
<Response>
  <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! I noticed that even when user hangs up before <Gather> timeout, <Redirect> call is still triggered. Which means the same issue - i can not distinguish people who hang up manually before timeout from people who actually waited for timeout. Any ideas how to make it work?